# Red joker or a red ace on either draw

Tags: probability, card-games

Suppose the two joker cards are left in a standard deck of cards. One joker is red and the other is black. A single card is drawn from the deck of 54 cards, returned to the deck, and a second card is drawn. Determine the probability of drawing a red joker or a red ace on either draw.

So there are two red aces and one red joker.

Instinctively, I would think $\frac{3}{54}\times\frac{3}{54}=\frac{1}{324} $

But 1 - Pr(no red joker or red ace on either draw) = $1-\frac{51}{54}\times\frac{51}{54}=\frac{35}{324} $

I can't figure this out...

Comment: $\frac{3}{54}\times\frac{3}{54}$ is the probability that *both* draws are a red Joker or a red Ace.  $1-\frac{51}{54}\times\frac{51}{54}$ that *at least one* draw is a red Joker or a red Ace.

Comment: Quite... If you insist on approaching directly, then this would be "both first and second draw" + "first but not second" + "second but not first" leading to a calculation of $\frac{3}{54}\times\frac{3}{54}+\frac{3}{54}\times\frac{51}{54}+\frac{51}{54}\times\frac{3}{54}$,  or perhaps a bit cleaner as "first" + "second but not first" leading to $\frac{3}{54}+\frac{51}{54}\times\frac{3}{54}$, both of which of course equal $\frac{35}{324}$, same as the indirect method yields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question asks you to determine the probability of drawing a red joker or a red ace on *either* draw. So your second attempt using complimentary method is correct. In your first approach you are calculating the probability that both draws are either a red ace or a red joker. The correct answer would be,

$ \displaystyle \frac{3}{54} \cdot \frac{51}{54} + \frac{51}{54} \cdot \frac{3}{54} + \frac{3}{54} \cdot \frac{3}{54} = \frac{35}{324}$